# Can a full teardown of my 318 TDS (1996 1.7 Gasoil) E36 engine have bad side effects?

Tags: engine, repair

I would like to get more acquainted with the engine of my car, learn mechanics, and also just clean the engine of accumulated dirt and grime.

As such, I am considering tearing down the engine.

For sure, afterwards, I would like to mount it back and get it to work, if possible, better than before!

Are there any significant risks with such an operation? Absolute NO-GO reasons?

Answer (score 9):

Well, if you fail to put it back together properly (even something as simple as reusing a non-reusable part or messing up on a torque/bolt-stretch calculation/install), you can cause a failure (possibly immediate, possibly some time down the road) that will destroy the engine.

If you're OK with that, it would be a wonderful learning experience.  However, if you're not a skilled mechanic and don't want to get stuck on the side of the road (and with a large repair bill), you may not wish to travel this road...

Answer (score 2):

I would get a good book that describes this engine...study the design etc. before I attempted anything like this, rather than just "go for it".

Reason being, there is a lot that goes into putting them back together that you will not see or even notice when you are taking it apart. So yes, it is very possible to screw it up, as it is ***not just a reversal*** of breaking it apart (breaking it apart is the easy part). My buddies have been doing this for years and they still run into problems all the time.

There are [many classes](http://www.pelicanparts.com/techarticles/Bruce-Jerry/bruce-jerry.htm) in the US for this, not sure about Vienna though.

However, if you can afford to make mistakes and are just "tinkering", then go for it.